# Android: Cannot use TabLayout in my design even after migration to Android X

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but I migrated my project to android X and still cannot use TabLayout in my layout files.

My dependencies in build.grade (app level):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'


    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.3.1'

    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'


    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I also tried to add:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

And then Android studio marks it as error and tells me to upgrade to Android X (which I did already)

If it matters, my compile sdk version is 29
build tools: 29.0.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`. It includes Tablayout

Comment: Oh thanks, you know I tried it before and it didn't work, apparently it does work after you exit and re-open android studio, syncing alone doesn't help...
Thanks!

Comment: Next time. You can invalidate cache and restart. it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Rahul I will